# what happens to child process if it execvp() is successful?

Tags: c

I have a question about the use of execvp(), for the following function, if I am in child process and the execvp() function is executed successfully (according to the man page, it will not return), if the script outside of else {} will keep working, which means if the execCmd() function will return any value?

```
int execCmd(char* args[10]) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid > 0) { // parent process
        /* do something */
    } else {
        if (execvp(*args, args) < 0) {
            printf("Execution Failed!"); 
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If execvp fails, you must call `_exit` not `exit`.

Answer (score 1):

If `execvp` is successful, the process starts executing the specified program.

```
Parent Process          Child Process
-------------------     -------------------
fork()
pid_t pid = ...;        pid_t pid = ...;
pid < 0                 pid < 0
pid > 0                 pid > 0
/* do something */      execvp(*args, args)
return 0;               [main of new program]
```

Your program could have been written

```
int execCmd(char** args) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        execvp(*args, args);
        perror("execvp");
        _exit(1);
    }

    /* ... Do something in parent ... */
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you probably want to wait for the child to finish, return the `pid` or have the child auto-reap (by making SIGCHILD ignored).

Comment: Corner-case nit, `_exit` should be used after a failed call to `execve` (of which all `execvX` functions are a wrapper for) because the call to `execve` removes registrations created using `atexit(3)` and `on_exit(3)` and `exit` will invoke undefined behavior if either were registered by the current process.

Answer (score 0):

in general, the code should not be executing misc statements;

The code should only need to test the results of the call to `fork()` once.

Notice, there is no need to wrap the call to `execvp()` in an `if()` code block

The parent process should wait for the child process to complete before exiting.

When an error occurs, should output an error message to `stderr` via a call to `fprintf( stderr, "...\n" )`  However, when the error is from a system function, the reason the system thinks the error occurred should also be output to `stderr`.  A simple way to accomplish this is by calling `perror()`

for ease of readability and understanding: separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.

the preferred code logic for a call to `fork()` is:

```
int execCmd(char* args[10])
{
    pid_t pid;

    switch( pid = fork() )
    {
        case -1:   // error
            perror( "fork failed" );
            exit(1);
            break;

        case 0:    // child
            execvp(*args, args);
            perror( "execvp Failed!" ); 
            exit(1);
            break;

        default:   // parent
            /* do something */
            waitpid( pid, NULL );
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```